# Is adding list in List of Lists added by reference?

Tags: java, arraylist, reference

I'm trying to understand java object references. What I learned so far is

1. Objects' references are passed by value, so adding something in that object will be available in the object after the method returns.
2. Creating a new object foo inside a method that received the object foo as argument will not reflect changes made on locally created foo object, on passed foo object.

Based on this knowledge, I'm trying to understand ***why the following code snippet isn't removing objects from current list that've been added to result list.***

The code below doesn't suffer from empty list at the end of recursion even though it's adding references of currentList to resultList & we're removing elements from currentList.

```
findCombations(condidates, 0, target, new ArrayList<Integer>(), result); 
public void findCombinations(int[] candidates, int index, Int target, List<Integer> currentList, List<List<Integer» result) { 
    if(target == 0) { 
        result.add(currentList); 
        return; 
    } 
    if(target < 0) { return; } 
    
    for(int i = index; i < candidates.length; i++) {
     if(i == index && candidates[i] != candidates[i - 1]) { 
         currentList.add(candidates[i]); 
         findCombinations(candidates, i + 1, target - candidates[i], currentList, result); 
         currentList.remove(currentList.size() - 1); //why removing numbers from this list not removing the numbers from the currentList that's been added to result list?
     }
 }
```

Can someone please help me understand this behavior?

**EDIT:**

This is a leetcode question that requires unique combinations that lead to target:
We've to find all the unique number combinations whose sum lead to the given target. We can't have duplicate sets/combinations.
The provided code is doing DFS on the given array & finding the combinations based on subtracting an element that it comes across in the array. There are 2 base cases, when the target == 0, we just add the currentList in resultList. CurrentList contains the numbers whose sum == target & the other base case is if target < 0, in that case, we end recursion.

```
Input: candidates = [10,1,2,7,6,1,5], target = 8,
A solution set is:
[
  [1, 7],
  [1, 2, 5],
  [2, 6],
  [1, 1, 6]
]
```

Comment: Could you explain what this code is supposed to do? Or perhaps create a *simpler program* without unnecessary bits to understand your question?

Comment: "why the following code snippet isn't removing objects from current list that've been added to result list." Can you show the result (or something) that leads you this conclusion?

Comment: Aside: what's the point in looping if you only ever do something when `i == index`? I'm not convinced this code would work, actually, because you'd get an AIOOBE when `index == 0`, because of accessing `candidates[i-1]`.

Comment: @Joni I've updated the question. Basically we're adding a number in the currentList & subtract that number from the given target, once our target is 0, we add in resultList, the currentList that contains all the numbers whose sum == target .

Comment: @user10286755 is your edit showing what it should do, what you expect it to do, or what it does do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is adding list in List of Lists added by reference?

Yes, it is. The method call `result.add(currentList)` adds a reference to `currentList` to the `result` list. Any changes that you make to `currentList` after this point will be seen also through "result," because it holds a reference to the same object.

Simplified example: intuitively you might think this program should print `[["hello"], []]` but instead it prints `[[], []]` because `result` holds two references to the same instance of list.

```
List<List<String>> result = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> currentList = new ArrayList<>();

currentList.add("hello");
result.add(currentList);

currentList.remove(0);
result.add(currentList);

System.out.println(result);
```

If you want to stop this from happening, you can create a copy of `currentList` when you add it to `result`.

```
// add a copy instead of a reference to the same list
result.add(new ArrayList<>(currentList));
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I'd the same idea however the given code above doesn't suffer from empty list issue even though we're storing references of the currentList in resultList. That's what confusing me. My apologies for forgetting to add this info

Comment: In the code in the question you never create a new list: every call to `result.add(currentList)` adds a reference to the same list object. In the end `result` will hold N references to the same list. If your expected output is supposed to contain *different lists* you do suffer from this issue.